# Rails multiple actions share one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails controller whose actions all share a similar view layout. Rather than duplicating the code in several different views I'd like all of the actions to share the same view (and perhaps even actions from another controller).

I realize this can be accomplished by adding a `render ...` call to every action and telling it to use the same view file, but is there any way I can hook this into a group of actions and avoid being explicit inside every single one?

Comment: This sounds like you should use before_filters. Your use case fits this perfectly. Then you will use layouts like Robin said.

Comment: I don't see how before_filters help me with rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you better explain why layouts don't work? I believe this code should solve your problem.

Let's say you have `UsersController` and you want all the actions, except new and create to use the same views. Then you can easily do:

```
def UsersController < ApplicationController
  layout "shared_layout", except: [:new, :create]
  layout "new_user_layout", only: [:new, :create]

  def show
    # Renders in app/views/layouts/shared_layout.html.erb
  end

  def index
    # Renders in app/views/layouts/shared_layout.html.erb
  end

  def new
    # Renders in app/views/layouts/new_user_layout.html.erb
  end

  def create
    # Renders in app/views/layouts/new_user_layout.html.erb
  end
end
```

Then you can create a layout which say what needs to be render in the shared. In `app/views/layouts/shared_layout.html.erb`

```
<html>
  <body>
    <%= render "shared/shared_partial_1.html.erb" %>
    <%= render "shared/shared_partial_2.html.erb" %>
    <%= render "shared/shared_partial_3.html.erb" %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will render partials 1, 2, and 3 in the same manner for all the actions of the controller. What is wrong with that?

Comment: I suppose he wanted to avoid having to duplicate code from his application layout (head section, footer etc...), but with partials, it becomes easily manageable, and I dont know of a better way to do it anyways.

Comment: Ok so I've revisited this and it still looks for the actions template file. That is, loading /users/index still looks for views/users/index.html.erb which if I'm sharing all of these views, wouldn't exist. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of solutions:

You can create a layout in `views/layout` specifically for these actions.

You would then set the layout in your controller:

```
class LalasController < ApplicationController
    layout "your_action_layout"
end
```

---

You might be talking about this when you're mentioning `render ...`, but you can create mini layouts from partials:

In `views/controller_names/my_layout`

```
<div class="my-layout">
    <%= yield %>
</div>
```

And then, in each of your actions, you would do:

```
<%= render layout: "my_layout" do %>
    <div></div> <!-- All the code of your view -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want to be explicit in all my actions like in the last example. I'm trying to avoid that. I would also prefer to avoid the layout route too because this means I need to repeated all of the content inside my `application.html.erb`

Comment: Well, if you split your application layout into partials, it shouldn't be a big deal to have another layout. Sorry but I don't have another solution.

Comment: Yeah it's just not idea. To be honest I didn't think there was another solution to this (which is why I asked it) I'll hold out for any other responses and default back to this way if not. Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Just bundle all the common code in your application layout into partials (_head.html.erb, _footer.html.erb etc), and you'll see that it's a pretty good solution overall ;)